# Is there a way to save a proxy authentication in my pc?

Tags: proxy, autoproxy

I'm behind a squid proxy installed on Windows Server 2003, I downloaded a game to play it on my free time at work, but the game requires to update and it can't do it because of the authentication proxy ( I gues it is), there's a way to update the game through the proxy authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/), it puts an authentication proxy on your local machine which you can use as a proxy from your program.

It basically authenticates for you once you have it set up.